# Host testing C program with hard coded memory addresses

Tags: c, linux, unit-testing, memory-management, functional-testing

We will write functional/unit tests for C code. This C program will be run as embedded software. However we need to run tests on a Linux environment.

The problem is that parts of the code under test looks like this:

my_addresses.h:

```
#define MY_BASE_ADDRESS     (0x00600000)
#define MY_OFFSET_ADDRESS   (0x108)
```

my_code.c

```
#include "my_addresses.h"

static const My_Type* my_ptr =
  (My_Type*)(MY_BASE_ADDRESS + MY_OFFSET_ADDRESS);

/* my_ptr is dereferenced and used ... */
```

Obviously, this will not run so well on Linux host environment.

Is there some way we can work around this issue during testing? Can we somehow "redirect" the program to use other addresses, that are valid addresses to memory allocated during test procedures?

Our first attempt was to replace "my_addresses.h" with another header file during tests, which (extern) declares variables instead of hard defines - then assign malloc'd memory to MY_BASE_ADDRESS, etc. The problem with that is the "static const" declaration in the c file. Of course you cannot assign a variable to a static const type.

Preferably, we should not modify the code under test (although in the worst case it may come to that).

Comment: That's not really practical as is... I think it should not work like that in the first place. Why on earth the addresses would be hard coded in the header? Your current problem is one of many you avoid by *not doing that*. Either you change your objects to be *under* the hard coded adresses, or you change your usage of those adresses to get the real place of the objects you want.

Comment: @Eregrith Yes, it's not practical (for host testing at least). But it's the way it is, and it's out of our hands to do anything about.

Comment: Should that be `static const My_Type * my_ptr `? Or do you have something like `typedef M_Type_t * My_Type`?

Comment: @PJTraill Yes, correct. "My_Type" was supposed to be a typedef for a pointer to a type. Updating the question to make the situation clearer (writing it as a pointer to My_Type instead).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could check for e.g. the `__linux__` macro and use conditional compilation. When on Linux use an array as base, and make it big enough to keep all the data needed in it.

Something like e.g.

```
#ifdef __linux__
int8_t array[1024];
# define MY_BASE_ADDRESS array
#else
# define MY_BASE_ADDRESS 0x00600000
#endif
```

Comment: If there is a lot of this stuff you may prefer to define an intermediate macro, e.g. `#ifdef __linux__` `#define FIXED_ADDRESSES 1` `#else` `#define FIXED_ADDRESSES 0` `#endif` ... `#if FIXED_ADDRESSES` etc. Or even `#ifdef __linux__` `#define ADDRESS_DECL(fixed, type, name, size) fixed` `#else` `#define ADDRESS_DECL(fixed, type, name, size) type name [size];` ... rats, this version is not going to fly!... `#endif`

Answer (score 0):

In the Linux environment you can define a global array and then use the address of this as your base pointer.

```
const char my_buffer[1024];
#define my_base_addr (&my_buff)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

- your embedded memory layout is small enough to model unchanged in its entirety (or in a few chunks) on Linux,
- your compiler is happy with the constant memory address expressions below, and
- `My_Type` in your example was defined as `typedef My_Type1_t * My_Type;`

you could (1) separate the definition of the embedded memory layout from deciding how it is placed and perhaps (2) gain some type-safety if you declare a `struct` for the layout:

```
#pragma (essential: stuff to force structs to contain no extra padding)
typedef struct {
  char pad0[0x108];
  My_Type1_t foo;
  char pad1[0x210];
  My_Type2_t bar;
  ...
} Memory_Layout_t;
#pragma (preferably: something to revert to previous struct layout options)
```

(If you don’t like calculating the size of `pad1`, use a `union`.)

Then make the variants:

```
#ifdef __linux__
Memory_Layout_t Embedded_Memory;
#  define Embedded_Memory_P (& Embedded_Memory)
#else
#  define Embedded_Memory_P ((Memory_Layout_t *) (0x00600000))
#endif
```

and reference it with

```
static const My_Type my_ptr = & Embedded_Memory_P->foo;
```